# Logical AND and OR with grep

Tags: search, grep, find, string

I want to extract the lines that matches the following logical operation:

```
"AB+CD" AND ("nonAB+nonCD" OR "nonAB+CD").
```

Which means I want lines with:

```
AB+CD,nonAB+nonCD
AB+CD,nonAB+CD
AB+CD,nonAB+nonCD,nonAB+CD
```

Meaning that I am looking for lines with "AB+CD" with **one** or **both** of ("nonAB+nonCD" OR "nonAB+CD").
Note that  the + is part of the string. I want to treat it as a string (character) not arithmetic operation.

What I did is using pipe to execute AND. And use \| for the OR. So My command is:

```
grep ',AB+CD' test.txt | grep ',nonAB+nonCD\|,nonAB+CD'
```

The first `|` is for piping. The second is logical OR for grep as per this [reference](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/10/grep-or-and-not-operators/) that gives this example for logical OR with grep:

```
grep 'pattern1\|pattern2' filename
```

The result that appears to me in the terminal colors (finds) the second part of the command. The first part (before the pipe `|` is not highlighted in the colored result. My question:

1) Is my command correct?

2) How to color the complete command findings?

Comment: The escape sequences for colouring the output are generated only on terminal output: if passed into a pipe, they could interfere with a subsequent match. You would therefore need to make the whole match with a single `grep` call. This should be possible with `grep -E` (or `egrep`), and I'll have a look at a possible match string. In your examples, `AB+CD` precedes `nonAB`: is this always the case? Your double search will match, even if `AB+CD` comes later.

Comment: No specific order in my case. Just `AB+CD` is a must. Then the others `,nonAB+nonCD` or `,nonAB+CD` at least one of them need to be matched.

Comment: Some initial tests show that the match will need to take the form `pattern1.*pattern2`, which means that all the intermediate characters between the two patterns will be part of the match and therefore coloured. Will this be satisfactory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `-P` option (PCRE):

```
grep -P 'AB\+CD,(?:nonAB\+nonCD|nonAB\+CD)' file.txt
```

**Output:**

```
AB+CD,nonAB+nonCD
AB+CD,nonAB+CD
AB+CD,nonAB+nonCD,nonAB+CD
```